# How to run kafka producer that is written in Python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new to Kafka but have seen a few tutorials so I know how Kafka works. I am trying to run a producer that I have written in Python but I don't know how to run this file after I have started my zookeeper server and kafka server. If anyone can tell me the structure of the command that is to be written in command prompt, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks!

Kafka Producer:

```
import json
import time
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
from kafka.future import log

if __name__ == "__main__":
  producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers= 'localhost: 9092')

future = producer.send('my-topic', b"test")

try:
    record_metadata = future.get( timeout=10)
except KafkaError :
    log.exeption()
    pass

print( record_metadata.topic)
print(record_metadata.partition)
print(record_metadata.offset)

producer = KafkaProducer(value_serializer = lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('ascii'))
producer.send('json-topic',{'key':'value'})

for _ in range (100):
    producer.send('my-topic', b"test")
    producer.send('my-topic',b"\xc2Hola, mundo!")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

So your question is how to run a python script? Simply save it, make executable and execute:

```
chmod +x ./kProducer.py
python ./kproducer.py
```

More detail are here: [How to Run a Python Script via a File or the Shell](http://pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I was working on windows I could not use chmod even though I got some direction from this. My problem isn't solved but I will ask it in separate post.

Comment: If you are in Windows you don't need to do a `chmod`, just run the script: `C:\pathTo\python.exe C:\pathTo\my_python_script.py`

Answer (score 1):

Add shebang line at the top to your script:

`#!/usr/bin/env python-version`
Replace the python-version with python2 for 2.x and python3 for 3.x
To check the version of python use the command: 
`python -V` 
The shebang line will determine the script ability to run as standalone. This will help when you want to double-click the script and execute it and not from the terminal. or simply say

`python scriptname.py`